# python on apache - getting 404

Tags: python, apache2

**I edited this question after i found a solution... i need to understand why the solution worked instead of my method?**

This is likely to be a silly question. I tried searching other questions that are related... but to no avail.

*i am running Apache/2.2.11 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.4 PHP/5.2.6-3ubuntu4.5 with Suhosin-Patch mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.6.2*

i have a script called test.py

```
#! /usr/bin/python
print "Content-Type: text/html"     # HTML is following
print                               # blank line, end of headers

print "hello world"
```

running it as an executable works...

```
/var/www$ ./test.py
Content-Type: text/html

hello world
```

when i run http://localhost/test.py   i get a 404 error.

What am i missing?

i used this resource to enable python parsing on apache.  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=91101

From that same thread... the following code worked.. **why?**
    #!/usr/bin/python

```
import sys
import time

def index(req):

# Following line causes error to be sent to browser
# rather than to log file (great for debug!)

    sys.stderr = sys.stdout

    #print "Content-type: text/html\n"

    #print """
    blah1 = """<html>
    <head><title>A page from Python</title></head>
    <body>
    <h4>This page is generated by a Python script!</h4>
    The current date and time is """

    now = time.gmtime()
    displaytime = time.strftime("%A %d %B %Y, %X",now)

    #print displaytime,
    blah1 += displaytime

    #print """
    blah1 += """
    <hr>
    Well House Consultants demonstration
    </body>
    </html>
    """
    return blah1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the mod_python's [Publisher Handler](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/tut-pub.html) is expecting to find `index` function in test.py.

You can call any function inside test.py by putting it in the end of URL, e.g. `http://localhost/test.py/any_func`, the default function being `index` if none given.

Comment: that looks like teh answer!  thank you. i'll accept as soon as stackoverflow allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your code working as is, you can also configure your web server to handle .pl as cgi script instead of using mod_python.publisher

on apache config:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

and if you don't want an error 403, edit:

```
<Directory /path/to/www/yourfile.py>
Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```